# Tinkerpop - Is it better to use Redis for key-value property indexes or to use KeyIndexableGraph

Tags: graph, redis, key-value, gremlin

Pretty straightforward question but I can't find the info that I want - is it advisable to use the KeyIndexableGraph of tinkerpop or to roll your own super performant key/index solution on the most performant and specialized stores like redis to get the node/edge locations you need?

It would appear to me that Redis should be better here as a technology that only focuses on key/value lookups and then pass the address in to the graph but I'd like to justify the costs.

The promise from tinkerpop is that index lookups should be log(n) on articles that are indexed with the property which is pretty good. Is it possible to do better in redis, or that the n*constant is much better than in the graph lookup?

Edit: I realized later this isn't really an intelligent question - Redis is an in memory store so is bounded by memory. Looking up a graph node location is still going to require a second lookup of the node in the graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important to remember that aside from TinkerGraph (an in-memory graph), TinkerPop is not a graph database on its own.  KeyIndexableGraph is an interface that is implemented by an underlying graph databases (Titan, Neo4j, OrientDB, etc.) utilizing that graph's index capability.  Therefore, you should make your indexing choice based on the capabilities of the underlying graph database itself.

Generally speaking, implementing Redis for indexing purposes for the graphs that do implement KeyIndexableGraph seems like an unnecessary layer.  I would guess that it will complicate your  programming without much benefit.

Comment: Second question of mine you've answered related - any chance I can snipe your contact information for some mentorship on a project I'm working on while I get ramped up on graph? Not a lot of people out there have the experience. Thanks again - I'm using orient but will likely flip to Titan on Cassandra with Faunus.

Comment: Marking as answered as I think this is a valid answer without giving running time inference. If someone else can give an answer of greater value I'll flip it out.

Comment: If you haven't already, I would suggest that you take questions that you have to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gremlin-users and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/aureliusgraphs  You'll get a lot of good help from people there, including me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the difference: 
Databases like OrientDb have apx O(log2n) lookup times on an index.
Reddis has O(1) - constant time lookup.